# Control Thickness of ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-progressbar, uiprogressbar

I have a progress Bar which is shown as below:
My question is v simple, how would i control the "thickness" of circular view as it seems to be too thick in my opinion. Thanks very much in Advance.

[image]

Comment: Use custom progress dialog, i mean you can use image of your own, otherwise you cannot control the thicknes of the default progress bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this for bar style

style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"

Comment: Many Thanks Gopal! It works but after adjusting the size, i find out that the original actually is the best fit. But i learn more on progress bar